# Convergence of partial sums of basis vectors in banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces

Let $B$ is some separable Banach space with Schauder basis $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^\infty \subset B$. Let $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ - is some sequence of complex numbers. Let $p_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i e_i$, is it true, that $p_n$ convergence is equivalent to $||p_n||$ convergence?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by $p_n$ convergence and $\| p_n \|$ convergence?

Comment: $p_n$ - convergence of vectors in strong sense (by norm), $||p_n||$ - convergence of norms - positive numbers.

Comment: @kp9r4d As the norm is continuous with respect to the topology it induces, the strong convergence implies the convergence of norms. On the other hand, let $B = L^{1}(I)$, the space of integrable functions over a real finite interval $I$. The sequence $f_{n}=(-1)^n$ does not converge in the strong sense, yet the sequence of norms does converge to $1$. Proof that it does not converge in the strong sense: suppose it does to some function $f$. Take $\epsilon = (1/2)\min\{\Vert f+1\Vert,\Vert f-1\Vert\}$. If $\Vert f+1\Vert = 0$ or $\Vert f-1\Vert=0$, it implies $f=-1$ a.e. or $f=1$ a.e. ...\...

Comment: .../... All cases lead to contradiction.

Comment: Your $f_n$ is not Schauder basis of $L^1(I)$.

Comment: @kp9r4d Sure, I presumed your question was more general and you just precised the context. Sorry for not having correctly addressed the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $B=c_0$ and let $(e_n)$ be the standard basis. Let $\alpha_j=1$. Then $||p_n||=1$ but $p_n$ does not converge.

Comment: Maybe it exists some abstract characterization of Banach spaces and basises in which it is true?

Comment: For example, it is obviously true in $l_1$ and $l_2$ spaces with standart basises.