# About сonvergence of partial sums of basis of Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces

Let $B$ is some separable Banach space with Schauder basis $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^\infty \subset B$. Let $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ - is some sequence of complex numbers. Let $p_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i e_i$, For which pairs $(B, \{e_i\}_{i=1}^\infty)$, $p_n$ convergence is equivalent to $||p_n||$ convergence? It is obviously truly for $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ with standart basises, but maybe it is exist abstract characterization?

I created another question before [Convergence of partial sums of basis vectors in banach space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1800853/convergence-of-partial-sums-of-basis-vectors-in-banach-space). But this question is slightly wider then question on link, and I dont think it is ethical to put off "right answer" flag from beautiful David Ulrich example and edit my previous question.

Upd: My assumption that sufficient condition - it is equivalence of basis $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ to standart basis in $\ell_1$ it is true?

Comment: It seems your question is closely related to the one you asked earlier today: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1800853/convergence-of-partial-sums-of-basis-vectors-in-banach-space, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but it is slightly different, What can I do in such situations?

Comment: I think linking both questions and shortly explaining their difference is fine. Just as you edited!